# Angular http post request failed

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm building a mobile app using **angular 8 / ionic 4** I'm trying to submit a form on my backend and it's **Wordpress custom endpoint**, The job of this endpoint is adding a **woocommerce** product into the cart.

When I'm trying to do the **post** request via **postman** it works and sends the product to the cart.

But when trying to do the same request using **angular** returning a succeed message **but** not sending the request to the cart as supposed to do so.

**My angular code:**

```js
  addYithCompositeToCart(id: any) {

    const { token } = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));

    let headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
      "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`,
      // 'Cookie': localStorage.getItem('cookie')
    };

    let data = {
      "ywcp_selection[153CE4EE-C1A0-6D39-9AD5-58B51C5AB306]": "-1",
      "ywcp_variation_id[153CE4EE-C1A0-6D39-9AD5-58B51C5AB306]": "124136",
      "ywcp_quantity[153CE4EE-C1A0-6D39-9AD5-58B51C5AB306]": "1",
      "ywcp_selected_product_value[153CE4EE-C1A0-6D39-9AD5-58B51C5AB306]": "10",
      "ywcp_selection[471BAD03-9C3B-B44E-8584-348A5F33F8A6]": "-1",
      "attribute_pa_sphere[471BAD03-9C3B-B44E-8584-348A5F33F8A6]": "5-75",
      "ywcp_variation_id[471BAD03-9C3B-B44E-8584-348A5F33F8A6]": "110359",
      "ywcp_quantity[471BAD03-9C3B-B44E-8584-348A5F33F8A6]": "1",
      "ywcp_selected_product_value[471BAD03-9C3B-B44E-8584-348A5F33F8A6]": "102552",
      "quantity": "1",
      "add-to-cart": "102491",
    }



    let payload = new FormData();
    // // data = new FormData();

    // payload; 
    for (let key in data) {
      payload.append(key, data[key]);
    }

    this.http.post(`${environment.host}yith-composite/add-item?id=${id}`, payload, {
      headers
    })
      .toPromise()
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });

  }
```

**the postman request also:**
[image]

## update

I figure what causes the problem with more validation on the backend side,

The body that I send from my angular app **not readable** on my backend, So it returns an **empty array**, on the other side the Postman body my PHP code reading it so because that it's working fine.

**The php code**

```php
function yith_custom_add_item( WP_REST_Request $request ) {
    $currentuserid_fromjwt = get_current_user_id();
    $user = get_user_by( 'id', $currentuserid_fromjwt );
    
    
    if( $user ) {
        
        $product_id = $_GET['id'];
        $url = get_permalink( $product_id );
        
        $cookie = 'wordpress_logged_in_856ec7e7dd32c9b2fc11b366505cf40d' . '=' . wp_generate_auth_cookie($currentuserid_fromjwt, time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60), 'logged_in') . ';';

        $cookie .='_icl_current_admin_language_d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e=en; wp_woocommerce_session_856ec7e7dd32c9b2fc11b366505cf40d=171%7C%7C1575326201%7C%7C1575322601%7C%7Cab91a0f0bbe0f3d5ae90dd5bdf7e396d; wfwaf-authcookie-5372c020d00bf5e1ea6c81123ff21ec1=171%7C%7C4574b4a9b1b62c8c7a1c1ae24cd4bd26d279bb5670fe87bcf7eb210835e43f22; _icl_current_language=en; PHPSESSID=5ed2009813f86633694a25e297d4ee06; wordpress_logged_in_856ec7e7dd32c9b2fc11b366505cf40d=deleted; woocommerce_items_in_cart=1; woocommerce_cart_hash=086ae7e00c53740163451a538fe8a9fc';


        if ( !empty($_POST) ) {
            $response = wp_remote_post( $url, array(
                'headers' => array(
                   'Cookie' => $cookie,
                   'Authorization' => $request->get_header('Authorization'),
                   'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                ),
                'body'    => $_POST,
                
            ));
            
            return $response;
        } else {
            return "No body";
        }

        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: What was the response that logged into console? And if call did reach backend how did it differ from the expected behavior

Comment: Same response as postman response. I think maybe what causes the problem is the way data send from angular as my backend support only **form/multipart**. 

But also I use the FormData function as code shown above

Comment: Then you should have changed the content-type attribute in your  post request as `multipart/form` instead of `application/x-ww....`

Comment: I don't think that cause the problem but I give it a try and didn't work, and small note the postman has same header of my code so it's `application/x-ww...` and it works fine

Comment: Youe mentioned  "but not sending the request to the cart as supposed to do so." And I asked what was the expected behavior and what is the difference, also you mentioned in one comment that both postmen and angular request are fetching same response, so am not able to understand the issue, can you please elaborate

Comment: I have updated the question and I figure out what causes the problem all details I have implemented above, thanks.

Comment: Now the response on both are diff the angular return `no body` but the postman returns an response for success adding product

Comment: Sorry in the above comment, content type I mentioned was not complete try changing headers content type to `multipart/form-data` and let me know as you can see even in post man the data is marked for formdata encoding

Comment: the above comment is change in angular code not php

Comment: Same the PHP can't see the angular body request as `$_POST`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203439/discussion-between-sri-venkata-pavan-kumar-mhs-and-hesham-shawky).

Answer (score 0):

> you must also allow cors policy over your php server also

you can do this by using access control allow origin in your headers

`<?php
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");`